# React-waypoint only logs first time

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to render a Row using react-waypoint for infinite scrolls, like in Ben Awards Video.
So far I managed to log all the items rendered onto the console. In the video, he then renders the index of the last item.

I'm trying to do the same with my code here

```js
<TableBody>
  {createData(props.filteredData, "flavs", limit).map((row, i) => (
    <React.Fragment key={row.name}>
      <Row row={row} />
      {i === createData(props.filteredData, "flavs", limit).length - 10 && (
        <Waypoint onEnter={() => console.log(i)} />
      )}
    </React.Fragment>
  ))}
</TableBody>;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

the number 50 is from where I set the limit using state so the viewport only renders 50 items.

here is the video for context: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9dRk3bxEbS8&t=306s from 4:35 onwards

My issue is that it only loads the number 1 when I scroll to the bottom and back. in his video, it logs the number every time he scrolled down and up.